# git is not enabled in this workspace in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am seeing "git is not enabled in this workspace" message when I hover over the tiny git icon at the left bottom even if the folder is the root of the git repository.

[image]

I have git on my path as well. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking for the git output in `View > Output` and switch to `Git` in the dropdown

Comment: looking at it but nothing is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking for the taskmanager in process and kill unnecessary "git.exe"

Comment: kage, you should consider adding more details

Comment: Sorry, My English is not so good...  

In the same condition, Too many "git.exe *32" runnning in my PC.  

After, I found that "git.exe *32" runnning whenever Git clicked.  

So, I think that this "git.exe *32" influence "git is not enabled in this workspace".  

After, When I kill "git.exe *32" and reboot, I confirm that git function work.

Comment: Probably should put ^ as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about an opened folder or file? Cannot load git? Try it. Because when you don't have any file open, git is not available.[Git not working without an opened folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAB9Q.png). Also you can check your user settings in order to check is git is enabled or no, File/Preferences/User Settings.

Comment: you don't need to open a file, you just need a .git directory. if you run git init on an empty folder you'll see the git-scm become active in vs code .